# Бот вк с модулем вики

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Пытаюсь сделать вк бота который на команду /search (ваш запрос) выводил информацию из вики, но выводит ошибку с тем что не существует "vk.message.send" вот код:

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
from wikipedia import wikipedia

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="...")

longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
session_api = vk_session.get_api()

wikipedia.set_lang("ru")


def sendMessage(user_id, text):
    vk.message.send(
        random_id = get_random_id(),
        user_id = user_id,
        message = text,)


for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me and event.text:
        peer_id = event.peer_id
        cmd = str(event.text).split(" ")
        if cmd[0] == '/search':
            try:
                to_find = str(event.text).replace(cmd[0] + " ", "")
                res = wikipedia.page(to_find)
                to_len = len(res.content) + 180 - len(res.content)
                message = res.title + "\n\n" + res.content[:to_len] + "\nПодробнее: " + res.url
                sendMessage(peer_id, message)
            except NameError:
                sendMessage(peer_id, "Использование: /search <Запрос>")
            except IndexError:
                sendMessage(peer_id, "Использование: /search <Запрос>")
```

Comment: И что получается надо сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь использовать библиотеку [vk](https://pypi.org/project/vk/), а импортируете только [vk_api](https://pypi.org/project/vk-api/).

Comment: нужно импортировать библиотеку вк?

Comment: Я дал ссылки на две библиотеки. Конструкция vk.message.send (та, где ошибка) взята из библиотеки vk (вы ее не подключаете), а остальные конструкции из vk_api (вы ее подключили).

Comment: спасибо большое